# How to remove trailing comma after final number in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, trailing

Trying to remove the comma that comes after the number 10. Tried every plausible workaround, but nothing's worked so far.

```
$i = 0;

while($i < 10) {
echo ++$i. ",";
}
```

Comment: It is an infinite loop. Can you show exact code to increase value of $i;

Comment: Forgot to add the ++$i which is in the example, I just forgot add it here.

Comment: How about not adding the final comma in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a loop in the first place. Use `implode()` to insert a delimiter between array elements.

```
echo implode(',', range(1, 10));
```

Comment: Thanks, man! And duly noted about not using loops to achieve this result!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using loop and `rtrim()` like this:

```
$i = 0;
$result = '';
while($i < 10) {
  $result .= ++$i. ",";
}

echo rtrim($result, ',');
```